# How to share applications between two windows 10 pcs

Tags: windows, windows-10, gpu

I have two pcs, one win 10 laptop and one desktop. I need to run specific software on the desktop and feed it to the laptop. Would it be possible to put excess processes from the laptop to the desktop? Like an extra set of hardware.

If it makes it any easier, the issue is that I have a face-tracking software that uses all of my gpu and I need it to run on the graphics card on another pc.

Comment: While, *possible*, it would likely not be *feasible*. The software would need to be designed to run on two PC's, and you'd need a high-speed connection for all the data, such as video info.

Comment: Will RDP connection meet your requirement? Use mstsc to remote connect from the desktop to the laptop and then run the software in the remote session?